# iCal file not importing

Tags: icalendar

I made a function in a python script that returns an ical file, but when I try to import it into busycal, it says "no events imported". I have checked and doublechecked, yet I can't find anything wrong with it. Here is a (short) example of such iCal file that doesn't work:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Ben//classtoical
X-WR-CALNAME:Classes
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20131129T141052Z
UID:20131129141052-50157600408285@mydomain.com
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20131204T18000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20131204T20000
SUMMARY:Contemporary Philosophy
LOCATION:F.4.113
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20131129T141052Z
UID:20131129141052-79836541033229@mydomain.com
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20131202T18000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20131202T20000
SUMMARY:Logic and Philosophy of Science
LOCATION:E.2.01
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the cause of the problem; the DTSTART and DTEND dates had only 1 zero to represent seconds instead of the required 2.

Original file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Ben//classtoical
X-WR-CALNAME:Classes
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20131129T141052Z
UID:20131129141052-50157600408285@mydomain.com
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20131204T18000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20131204T20000
SUMMARY:Contemporary Philosophy
LOCATION:F.4.113
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20131129T141052Z
UID:20131129141052-79836541033229@mydomain.com
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20131202T18000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20131202T20000
SUMMARY:Logic and Philosophy of Science
LOCATION:E.2.01
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Working file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Ben//classtoical
X-WR-CALNAME:Classes
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20131129T141052Z
UID:20131129141052-50157600408285@mydomain.com
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20131204T180000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20131204T200000
SUMMARY:Contemporary Philosophy
LOCATION:F.4.113
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20131129T141052Z
UID:20131129141052-79836541033229@mydomain.com
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20131202T180000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20131202T200000
SUMMARY:Logic and Philosophy of Science
LOCATION:E.2.01
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```